# How can I get the output of languageDetector?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, i18next

I use i18next with LanguageDetector.

So I also use datetimePicker and want to say:

```
<DateTimePicker 
  locale={LangaugeDetector}
/>
```

I can also use expo-localization but when the user change the language with i18next then my locliatzion shows the old language. So is there any way to use LanguageDetector to get the current Language

Answer (score 0):

Use [i18next.resolvedLanguage](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#resolvedlanguage) or [i18next.language](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#language)

An example on how resolvedLanguage is used can also be found in [this example](https://github.com/locize/react-i18next-example-app/blob/main/src/App.js#L26) explained in [this blog post](https://locize.com/blog/how-to-internationalize-react-i18next/#language-switcher).